# How to move line with finger?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-graphics

I am defining the following variables in my ViewController for a line.

```
var scanlineRect = CGRect.zero
var scanlineStartY: CGFloat = 0
var scanlineStopY: CGFloat = 0
var topBottomMargin: CGFloat = 30
var scanLine: UIView = UIView()
```

I can draw a line using UIView and can move it in vertical direction using UIView.animate method. How to move a line dragging it with finger?

```
func drawLine() 
{
    self.view.addSubview(scanLine)
    scanLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scanlineRect = CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 30, height: 5)
    scanlineStartY = topBottomMargin
    scanlineStopY = self.view.frame.height - topBottomMargin
    scanLine.frame  = scanlineRect
    scanLine.center = CGPoint(x: scanLine.center.x, y: scanlineStartY)
    scanLine.isHidden = false
}
func Move(Location : CGPoint) 
{
    scanLine.isHidden = false
    weak var weakSelf = scanLine
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
        weakSelf!.center = CGPoint(x: weakSelf!.center.x, y: Location.y)
    }, completion: nil)

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{    
    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    if let touch = touches.first
    {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
    }
    Move(Location: lastPoint)
}

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    drawLine()
}
```

Comment: FYI - Unrelated to your question but do not force-unwrap `weakSelf` in your `Move` method. Unwrap it properly because it might be `nil` and crash your app.

Comment: Are you merely asking how to drag a view????

Comment: Nothing to do with Xcode or Core Graphics, by the way.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I unwrap it properly and avoid app crash?

Comment: Unwrap it like you do any other optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `touchesMoved` instead of `touchesBegan`

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) else{
        return
    }
    scanLine.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x-scanLine.frame.size.width/2, y: location.y-scanLine.frame.size.height/2)
}
```

## updated

If you want only move in **y axis only** you need to change this line

```
scanLine.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x-scanLine.frame.size.width/2, y: location.y-scanLine.frame.size.height/2)
```

**use this instead** note that `scanline.frame.origin.x` is unchanged

```
scanLine.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: scanLine.frame.origin.x, y: location.y-scanLine.frame.size.height/2)
```

Comment: I cannot compile. I have following errors:
Value of Type ViewController has no member "superview". 
Value of Type ViewController has no member "frame"

Comment: Why did you change all of the good code the OP has in their `touchesBegan` method and replace it with bad Swift code just to say `touchesBegan` should be changed to `touchesMoved`? This is Swift, don't use semicolons. This is a view controller, use `self.view`, not `self.superview`. In Swift, don't check a variable against `nil` and then force-unwrap if it isn't. Instead, safely unwrap the variable, just like in the OP's original code.

Comment: @rmaddy It was a old code I don't review it a lot, is my bad, now I had updated my answer please can you tell me if its a bad code? I always appreciate your comments, best regards

Comment: @ReinierMelian I checked your answer. It's ok, but how can I disable right/left movement? I need to move only up and down.

Comment: @Vladislav check my answer again